# Is there a simple way to replace a comma with nothing?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a string list into floats but this can't be done with a number like 1,234.56.
Is there a way to use the string.replace() function to remove the comma so i just have 1234.56?
string.replace(',','') doesn't seem to work. This is my current code:

```
fileName = (input("Enter the name of a file to count: "))
print()

infile = open(fileName, "r")
line = infile.read()
split = line.split()
for word in split:
    if word >= ".0":
        if word <= "9":
            add = (word.split())
            for num in add:
                  x = float(num)
                  print(x)
```

This is my error I'm getting:

> > > > File "countFile.py", line 29, in main
> > > >             x = float(num)
> > > >         ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,236.789'

Comment: If it matters, I would like to print the sum of the floats for my final step.

Comment: Just use str.replace() function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a string you can replace any character, such as `,`, like so:

```
s = "Hi, I'm a string"
s_new = s.replace(",", "")
```

---

Also, the comparisons you are doing on the strings may not always perform the way you expect. It may be better to cast to numeric values first. Something like:

```
for word in split:
    n = float(word.replace(",", ""))
    # do comparison on n, like
    # if n >= 0: ...
```

---

As a tip, try reading in your file with `with`:

```
# ...
with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # this will give you `line` as a string 
        # ending in '\n' (if it there is an endline)
        string_wo_commas = line.replace(",", "")
        # Do more stuff to the string, like cast to float and comparisons...
```

This is a more idiomatic way to read in a file and do something to each line.

Comment: I've tried adding this in various parts of my code and i get this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: `replace` is a string method. It can only be used on a string, not a list of strings (or list of anything else for that matter). I've updated my answer with an example of how to read each line of the file in as a string and do something to it a bit more easily. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this: [How do I use Python to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-th) and this: [How to delete a character from a string using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python)

Also, note that your `word >= ".0"` comparisons are `string` comparisons, not numerical.  They may not do what you think they will.  For example:

```
>>> a = '1,250'
>>> b = '975'
>>> a > b
False
```

Comment: I'm pulling the numbers from a text file. Is there a better way to pull only the numbers without getting the words between them?

Comment: That's hard to answer without knowing anything about the format of the text and numbers in the file, but you could use a regular expression.  For example, you could tokenize the text and then choose to process anything that matches the regular expression `[0-9]+,?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` or something. You could simplify it and process any token that starts with `[0-9]` (look up `search()` and `match()` in the Python `re` module)