# How do I cut out a few characters in the middle of a string? (Python 2.7.8)

Tags: python-2.7

I need to take a 6-significant-digit number and make it a 3-significant-digit number, but the string is structures as this:

string1 = 1.00466E+15

and I need

string2 = 1.00E+15

How do I cut out the 5th, 6th, and 7th character from this string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a character from a string using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python)

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem? If not, what other issues are you having?

Answer (score 2):

`string2 = string1[:4] + string1[7:]`

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings - specifically 'slicing'