# Splitting Strings within an Array

Tags: python, arrays, regex, parsing

I am writing a program in python that reads in a text file and executes any python commands within it. The commands may be out of order, but each command has a letter ID such as `{% (c) print x %}`

I've been able to sort all the commands with in the document into an array, in the correct order. My question is, how to i remove the (c), so i can run `exec(statement)` on the string?

Here is the full example array

```
[' (a) import random ', ' (b) x = random.randint(1,6) ', ' (c) print x ', ' (d) print 2*x ']
```

Also, I am very new to python, my first assignment with it.

Comment: sample of array , so that we can find a way to remove

Comment: Split, take all but the first, second, and last, then join with spaces

Comment: `str.replace('(c)', '')`

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan meant to add that. editing now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a character from a string using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python)

Comment: yes .. just one or two line from array ..

Comment: `exec(statement[5:])` try this it will help .. i tried to get substring so that it doesnot include the (a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the index part, by using substring:

```
for cmd in arr:
   exec(cmd[5:])
```

Comment: This was the quickest method, and it worked the best because I didn't want to completely remove the index. On account of it will be used later.

Comment: It is nice that it is short, quick and easily explained :-)  However, a regex approach will survive changes to the whitespace and having a command-id of more than one character for a bigger input.

Answer (score 1):

Take everything right to the parenthesis and exec:

```
for cmd in arr:
    exec(cmd.split(") ")[-1])
```

Comment: I see how this works, and I like it. How ever I get an invalid syntax error for my for loop. I used my own variables of course, but once I figure that error out I will probably use this.

Answer (score 1):

Stripping the command-id prefixes is a good job for a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#module-re):

```
>>> import re
>>> commands = [' (a) import random ', ' (b) x = random.randint(1,6) ', ' (c) print x ', ' (d) print 2*x ']
>>> [re.search(r'.*?\)\s*(.*)', command).group(1) for command in commands]
['import random ', 'x = random.randint(1,6) ', 'print x ', 'print 2*x ']
```

The meaning of regex components are:

- `.*?\)` means "Get the shortest group of any characters that ends with a closing-parentheses."
- `\s*` means "Zero or more space characters."
- `(.*)` means "Collect all the remaining characters into *group(1)*."

How this explanation makes it all clear :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the pattern looks simple and consistent, you could use regex.

This also allows for both `(a)` and `(abc123)` as valid IDs.

```
import re

lines = [
    ' (a) import random ',
    ' (b) x = random.randint(1,6) ',
    ' (c) print x ',
    ' (d) print 2*x '
]

for line in lines:
    print(re.sub(r"^[ \t]+(\(\w+\))", "", line))
```

Which would output:

```
 import random 
 x = random.randint(1,6) 
 print x 
 print 2*x
```

*If you really only want to match a single letter, then replace `\w+` with `[a-zA-Z]`.*

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple regex to omit the first alpha character in braces as:

```
import re

lst = [' (a) import random ', ' (b) x = random.randint(1,6) ', ' (c) print x ', ' (d) print 2*x ']

for ele in lst:
    print re.sub("^ \([a-z]\)", "", ele)
```