# replace characters in string with new word

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have an array of strings, and would like to make some replacements. For example:

```
my_strings = [['hi / hello world &'], ['hi / hello world'], ['it\90s the world'], ['hello world'], ['hello "world"']]

new_strings = [['hi and hello world'], ['hi and hello world'], ["it's the world"], ['hello world'], ['hello world']]
```

How can I replace / with and, remove & and \90, and remove "" around words, if a string in the array contains these characters?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Comment: Take a look at the replace method in the official docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: Actually, you don't have an array of strings.  Using your misnomer (it should be "list", not "array"), you have an array of arrays of strings.  Is there any reason for the extra `[` and `]` around each string?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should create a `dict` object to map the word with it's replacement. For example:

```
my_replacement_dict = {
    "/": "and", 
    "&": "",   # Empty string to remove the word
    "\90": "", 
    "\"": ""
}
```

Then iterate over your list and [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) the words based on above dict to get the desired list:

```
my_list = [['hi / hello world &'], ['hi / hello world'], ['it\90s the world'], ['hello world'], ['hello "world"']]
new_list = []

for sub_list in my_list:
    # Fetch string at `0`th index of nested list
    my_str = sub_list[0]   
    # iterate to get `key`, `value` from replacement dict
    for key, value in my_replacement_dict.items():  
         # replace `key` with `value` in the string
         my_str = my_str.replace(key, value)   
    new_list.append([my_str])   # `[..]` to add string within the `list`
```

Final content of `new_list` will be:

```
>>> new_list
[['hi and hello world '], ['hi and hello world'], ['its the world'], ['hello world'], ['hello world']]
```

Comment: Judging by OPs questions they might be new to python. Could you explain a little more detail in your code. For example explain why you are calling `sub_list[0]`. It might help OP to know that you are calling the index 0 of each sub list and why you are doing it.

Comment: @BaconTech Fair enough. Added the steps as comments

Answer (score 0):

As seen in that post : [How to delete a character from a string using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python)

You can use, for example, something like that

```
if "/" in my_string:
    new_string = my_string.replace("/", "and")
```

And include it in a loop over your whole array.