# python remove some words and space from string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list looks like this

```
['Drexel University,\r\n                  Antoinette Westphal COMAD,\r\n                  Animation & Visual Effects,\r\n                  Undergraduate Program']
```

I want to remove the university name, which is "Drexel University", and the space like \r\n (include those white space after that) in front of other words. I guess regex would be a good idea. But I don't know how to exclude some words with regex.

Well, I already have a solution. But if anyone could provide a regex version, I'll be appreciate.

Comment: So it's a single element list with one string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a character from a string using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python)

Comment: @COLDSPEED Yes, I think string or list is not the main problem. The reason I keep the list there is I think there might be some more convenient way to split it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you plan on doing this regularly for other words as-well. I would generalize it a bit.

From your data:

```
l = ['Drexel University,\r\n                  Antoinette Westphal COMAD,\r\n                  Animation & Visual Effects,\r\n                  Undergraduate Program']
```

Assign string to variable:

```
l = l[0]
```

Define the list of keys you want to ignore:

```
ignore_keys = ["Drexel University,","\n","\r","  "]
```

Loop over keys to ignore and replace them with blank

```
for ignore in ignore_keys:
    l = l.replace(ignore,"")
```

Then depending on how you want the result represented:

As list - `l.split(",")`
As string - `l`

Result:

```
print(l.split(","))
['Antoinette Westphal COMAD', 'Animation & Visual Effects', 'Undergraduate Program']

print(l)
'Antoinette Westphal COMAD,Animation & Visual Effects,Undergraduate Program'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` to split by whitespace and then slice the list as the following:

```
>>> l = ['Drexel University,\r\n                  Antoinette Westphal COMAD,\r\n                  Animation & Visual Effects,\r\n                  Undergraduate Program']
>>> l = l[0].split()[2:]
>>> l
['Antoinette', 'Westphal', 'COMAD,', 'Animation', '&', 'Visual', 'Effects,', 'Undergraduate', 'Program']
```

If you want it as a string with a space between each word you can use `l = ' '.join(l)`

Comment: Seems that is not the way I want. If you split it word by word, the phrase structure would be broken. I want to get a result looks like: Antoinette Westphal COMAD, Animation & Visual Effects, ...

Comment: Oh well, I get it. Let discipline be the string. Then l=[d.strip() for d in discipline[0].split(',')]  works.

Answer (score 0):

To turn your list of one text into a list of strings, you can do:

```
l = ['Drexel University,\r\n                  Antoinette Westphal COMAD,\r\n                  Animation & Visual Effects,\r\n                  Undergraduate Program']

text = l[0]
lines = [line.strip().strip(',') for line in text.splitlines()]
```

Here, I extracted the first item of the list.
Then I split the first item into lines, and for each line I use `strip` to remove the spaces and the ",".

The result is:

```
['Drexel University', 'Antoinette Westphal COMAD',
 'Animation & Visual Effects', 'Undergraduate Program']
```

To remove the first element of the list, you can do:

```
lines.pop(0)
```

**EDIT: RegEx**

Using RegEx, you can split your text as below:

```
import re

text = l[0]
lines = re.split(r',\s+', text)
```

Comment: Nice, I just got the solution in a similar way.