# How to remove a particular substring from a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

I have two lists,

```
y1=['fem j sex / male \n', "  father's name  diwan singh saggu   \n", "elector's name   rahul saggu \n", 'identity card \n', 'zfk0281501', 'age as on 1.1.2008   23 \n']

word=["sex","father's","name","elector's","name","identity","card","age"]
```

I need to remove all the strings in `y1` which is in `word`.
I need to get output as

```
output=['fem j /male','diwan singh saggu','rahul saggu','zfk0281501','as on 1.1.2008 23']
```

I have split individual elements in y1 and tried comparing it with word.But i dont know what to do next? How to remove the strings??Here is what i tried,

```
y1new=[]
for y in y1:
    tmp=y.split()
    y1new.append(tmp)
for i in y1new:
    for j in i:
        if j in word:
            y1new[i].remove(y1new[i][j])
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I tried using the split() to split the strings and then searched those strings with word.If it came true i used replace() to remove from y1.But it didn't worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this program !

It will work perfectly !
Also I am attach the output of the program .

```
y1=['fem j sex / male \n', "  father's name  diwan singh saggu   \n", "elector's name   rahul saggu \n", 'identity card \n', 'zfk0281501', 'age as on 1.1.2008   23 \n']
word=["sex","father's","name","elector's","identity","card","age","\n"]

output =[]            //output list
for i in range(0,len(y1)): 
  for j in range(0,len(word)):
    a=y1[i].find(word[j])           //finds the word in a y1 list , if it found & returns index greater than -1 than replace the substring in a y1 list with empty string ' '
    if a!=-1:
      y1[i]=y1[i].replace(word[j],'')
  y1[i]=y1[i].strip()            //removes the leading & trailing whitespaces 
  if y1[i]!='':
    output.append(y1[i])         // adds into the 'output' list

print(output)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CODE:

```
temp = ""
for y1_sentence in y1:
    y1_word = y1_sentence.split(" ")

    for i in y1_word:
        if i not in word:
            temp = temp + " " + i
    output.append(temp)
    temp = ""

real_output = []

for output_string in output:
    temp1 = output_string.strip()
    real_output.append(temp1)
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvM9U.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIzBF.png)

Answer (score -1):

Good morning,

there is a function in python called `str.replace(old, new[, max])`.

`old` stands for the old substring to be replaced.

`new` stands for the new substring, which would replace old substring.

`max` is optional, not needed in your case.

It is also important to mention that strings are immutable in python. That means you have to assign the return value of `replace()` to your used variable.

```
for x in y1:
    for w in word:
        x = x.replace(w, "")
```

This should work just  fine, but I am sure there is a smarter way to do it in Python. Just have a look here for example:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Comment: I tried using replace(),but it didnt came as i expected.May be my logic is wrong,

Comment: It is the best way. Have a look at older questions and at the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help guys,i finally managed to solve the problem.Don't mind the variable names.I was too lazy there.

```
output=[]
y1new=[]
p=[]
word=["sex","father's","name","elector's","name","identity","card","age"]
y1=['fem j sex / male \n', "  father's name  diwan singh saggu   \n", "elector's name   rahul saggu \n", 'identity card \n', 'zfk0281501', 'age as on 1.1.2008   23 \n']

for y in y1:
    tmp=y.split()
    y1new.append(tmp)


for y in range(0,len(y1new)):
    tmp=y1new[y]
    for i in range(0,len(tmp)):
        if tmp[i] in word:
            p.insert(0,y1[y].replace(str(tmp[i])," " ))
            y1.remove(y1[y])
            y1.insert(y,p[0].replace(str(tmp[i])," " ))
for i in y1:
    tp=i.split()
    tp = ' '.join(tp)
    output.append(tp)
...........................................................................................
```

output

```
output
Out[14]: 
['fem j / male',
 'diwan singh saggu',
 'rahul saggu',
 '',
 'zfk0281501',
 'as on 1.1.2008 23']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex:

```
import re
y1=['fem j sex / male \n', "  father's name  diwan singh saggu   \n", "elector's name   rahul saggu \n", 'identity card \n', 'zfk0281501', 'age as on 1.1.2008   23 \n']
word=["sex","father's","name","elector's","name","identity","card","age"]
new_y1 = [re.sub('\n+|(?<=^)\s+|\s+(?=$)', '', re.sub('|'.join(word), '', i)) for i in y1]
```

Output:

```
['fem j  / male', 'diwan singh saggu', 'rahul saggu', '', 'zfk0281501', 'as on 1.1.2008   23']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
y1=['fem j sex / male \n', "  father's name  diwan singh saggu   \n", "elector's name   rahul saggu \n", 'identity card \n', 'zfk0281501', 'age as on 1.1.2008   23 \n']

word=["sex","father's","name","elector's","name","identity","card","age"]

result=[]
for j in y1:
    data=j.split()
    for m,k in enumerate(data):
        if k in word:
            del data[m]
    result.append(" ".join(data))

print(result)
```

output:

```
['fem j / male', 'name diwan singh saggu', 'name rahul saggu', 'card', 'zfk0281501', 'as on 1.1.2008 23']
```