# How to delete non-common elements between strings in python?

Tags: python, string

I want to delete all the letters in two strings that are not the same between them.

> For example:
>
> str1 = 'abcdefg'
>
> str2 = 'efghijk'

After removing the different characters I want to get:

> str1 = 'efg'
>
> str2 = 'efg'

I have the following code:

```
for i in str1:
    if i not in str2:
        str1 = str1.replace("i", "")  #delete that element
                                      #strings are immutable so I create a new string and remove that element
```

Then I would do the same with the other string.
However, when I print it out it does not delete all the elements I want it to. Or sometimes it doesn't delete any of the elements.
I have also tried it with a double for loop but it does not work correctly. 
Is there something wrong with my logic?

Comment: I believe you are replacing the literal letter `i` with a blank. You aren't using the variable that you called `i`, you are using the string `"i"`.

Comment: Based on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python, I wanted to delete that element

Comment: @ce1 but you are replacing the actual string `"i"`. You should use `i`, not `"i"`

Comment: You code says "find the letter i and replace it with a blank". You don't want to "find the letter i", you want to "find the letter that the variable i holds".

Comment: Yes that makes sense! that was my mistake. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a simple list comprehension and then assign the elements to a string

```
new_str = ''.join([i for i in str1 if i in str2])
```

Your error is here:

```
str1 = str1.replace("i", "")
```

should be

```
str1 = str1.replace(i, "")
```

Take note, this solution, being quadratic in the input size, is relatively inefficient and should not be used for large strings.

Comment: @EliKorvigo the question is not concerned about efficiency. If this answer does not supply a valid solution then a down vote would be just.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the common elements as follows

```
common = set(str1) & set(str2)
```

Then you can simply filter your strings not to include those elements as

```
str1 = ''.join([i for i in str1 if i in common])
str2 = ''.join([i for i in str2 if i in common])
```

Comment: Couldn't we get the same result without first having to find the common elements ?`
`str1 = ''.join([i for i in str1 if i in str2])` then `str2 = ''.join([i for i in str2 if i in str1])`
We'll first keep the elements of str1 that are also in str2 (common elements), then use said found common elements to change str2 in the desired way.

Comment: That's true, we can get the same result in this way. If however we have more strings this approach becomes cumbersome. Also, if the strings are long, then checking if element is in a `set` is much faster O(1), in contrast to checking if it exists in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (if you don't care about the order) is to use sets:

```
>>> str1 = 'abcdefg'
>>> str2 = 'efghijk'
>>> common = ''.join(set(str1) & set(str2))
>>> common
'feg'
```

Comment: I did not see your comment about order, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets even if you do care about order.  Just sort it:

```
>>> 
>>> str1 = 'abcdefg'
>>> str2 = 'efghijk'
>>> ''.join(sorted(set(str1) & set(str2), key = str1.index))
'efg'
>>> ''.join(set(str1) & set(str2))
'egf'
>>> str2 = 'egfhijk'
>>> ''.join(set(str1) & set(str2))
'egf'
>>> ''.join(sorted(set(str1) & set(str2), key = str1.index))
'efg'
>>>
```