# Convert float to string without point/comma in python

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I was wondering it there is a simple way to convert a float, for example `0.25`, into a string without the point/float, i.e. like `025`.
Is it possible? I'm searching for something that works for all floats. Thanks.

Comment: Could you try just removing characters? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3559600/4510954

Comment: What's the use-case? Under what you're asking for, the float values `12.50` and `1.25` would both be converted into `125`. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex replacement with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) in the case where there are both commas and decimal points. `re.sub()` replaces all occurrences of a *pattern* in the string by the replacement *repl*. If the pattern isn’t found, the string is returned unchanged.

```
import re

number = '999,123,456.345'
filtered = re.sub('[.,]', '', number)

print(filtered)
```

Output

> 999123456345

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest way is to just replace string

```
str(0.25).replace('.','')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`str.replace()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm):

```
def float2str(s):
    return str(s).replace('.', '')

print(float2str(0.25))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
025
```

Using reduce:

```
from functools import reduce

x = "3,766.989"
replacements = (',', '', '.', '')
print(reduce(lambda s, sep: s.replace(sep, ''), replacements, x))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
3766989
```