# How does len()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to understand the following code: `first[_last_three_letter_firstName -3:]`, but how does this work? because `len` will count the number of characters, and how does that behave? Because in `temp_passwd` receives `first[and the value obtained by len() - 3:]`:

```
first_name = 'Matheus'
last_name = 'Silva'

   def passwd_generator(first, last):
      _last_three_letter_firstName = len(first)
      _last_three_letter_lastName = len(last)

      temp_passwd = first[_last_three_letter_firstName -3:] + last[_last_three_letter_lastName -3:]

      return temp_passwd

_test_passwd = passwd_generator(first_name, last_name)
print(_test_passwd)
```

Comment: in this Post you can find  a Good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559/how-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-using-python

Comment: And here you have a good tutorial like explanation in number 3. and 5.: https://snakify.org/en/lessons/strings_str/

Comment: "How does len()?" is not a grammatically complete question, and the rest of your question doesn't help to clarify what exactly you want an answer to.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to know the length of a string

```
str = "Hello world"
str[-3:]
```

and

```
str = "Hello world"
str[len(str)-3:]
```

both will return the last three characters

```
'rld'
```

By the way, you can shorten whole passwd_generator function to this:

```
def passwd_generator(first, last):
    return f'{first[-3:]}{last[-3:]}'
```

if you use Python3, of course

Answer (score 0):

The `len()` function would return the length of the `_last_three_letter_firstName` and the index slice `first[_last_three_letter_firstName -3:]` would return the slice from three before the last character to the end.

So in this case `first[_last_three_letter_firstName -3:]` would return `'eus'`.

You could follow similar steps for `last[_last_three_letter_lastName -3:]`.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use colon there in the temp_password because the `len()` function calculate the length of the variable and slicing begin from 0 and you are trying to subtract with 3 how could you the you desire output and when use slicing

```
temp_passwd = first[_last_three_letter_firstName -3:] + last[_last_three_letter_lastName -3:]
```

in type of statement don't use colon.

And when you have a bunch of rows and columns and you wanted to get  the particular row or column so that time you can use slicing over there understood