# How to correct C code syntax errors from a file in Python?

Tags: python, c, parsing, syntax, automation

I have a very large .xlsx file(over 10000 lines of code) that contains a code written in C but has a lot of syntax errors and I need to convert it (using Python) to C code and syntax correct in C language.
Is there a way to automatically check for syntax errors and fix it?

A sample code of code in that xlsx file:

```
raw=phys

Xposition=fDistX+MountingOffserLong+WheelBase
if (Xposition>255,75)
\{
raw = 255,75/0.0625
\}
else if (Xposition<0)
\{raw = 0
StatusMeasurementXX=0x3h (invalid)
ObjectInvalid = 1
\}
else
\{
raw = Xposition/0.0625
\}
/* ObjectInvalid flag will be..... */

if (ObjectInvalid<1) then
\{ do nothing \}
else
\{
raw=100
\}
```

And I want to transform that code to look like this:

```
raw=phys;

Xposition=fDistX+MountingOffserLong+WheelBase;
if (Xposition>255,75)
{
raw = 255,75/0.0625;
}
else if (Xposition<0)
{
raw = 0;
StatusMeasurementXX=0x3h; //(invalid)
ObjectInvalid = 1;
}
else
{
raw = Xposition/0.0625;
}
/* ObjectInvalid flag will be..... */

if (ObjectInvalid<1)
{}
else
{
raw=100;
}
```

Comment: If that was possible, we wouldn't *have* syntax errors.

Comment: If all you want to do is strip the back slashes from the source, that ought to be easy enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559559

Comment: Why do you have a *spreadsheet* full of broken C in the first place, anyway?

Comment: Stripping out the back slashes won't fix all of your syntax errors, but it should fix most of them.  You can then use a decent IDE on the rest.

Comment: Track down the source of the spreadsheet. Probably it is clean C code and the syntax errors have been introduced during the questionable process of putting it in there.

Comment: Are those `255,75` ok, for you? Or they need some correction you didn't mention?

Comment: Those are ok @RobertoCaboni