# remove characters from every file name in directory with python

Tags: python, loops

So I am writing a piece of code that needs to iterate through hundreds of files in a directory. With every filt it needs to filter out certain pieces of information in it then put it in a new file with a modified name.

For example, a file called `1100006_0.vcf` or `5100164_12.vcf`  must have a file created called `1100006.vcf` and `5100164.vcf` respectively. Can you point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3559559/6131611

Comment: You might want to be more specific about that constraint. Are you just looking to remove everything after the underscore (including the underscore)?

Comment: Do you need to do this only for .vcf files ?

Comment: yes, only including and after the underscore, and the only files I am working with are .vcf s oyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** To make code Generic and rename file names from one directory to any other directory/folder try following. I have kept this program inside `/tmp` and renamed the files inside `/tmp/test` and it worked fine(in a Linux system).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
DIRNAME="/tmp/test"
files = os.listdir(DIRNAME)
for f in files:
    if '.vcf' in f:
        newname = f.split('_')[0]
        newname = newname + '.vcf'
        os.rename(os.path.join(DIRNAME,f), os.path.join(DIRNAME,newname))
```

---

---

Since you want to rename the files, so we could use `os` here. Written and tested with shown samples in python3, I have given `DIRNAME` as `/tmp` you could give your directory where you want to look for files.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os

DIRNAME="/tmp"
files = os.listdir(DIRNAME)
for f in files:
    if '.vcf' in f:
        newname = f.split('_')[0]
        newname = newname + '.vcf'
        os.rename(f, newname)
```

Answer (score 0):

As posted by RavinderSingh13, the code was fine, the only issue was that in renaming them, I would have two files of the same name (the difference between them was the underscore and number that I needed removed).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os

DIRNAME="/tmp"
files = os.listdir(DIRNAME)
for f in files:
    if '.vcf' in f:
        newname = f.split('_')[0]
        newname = newname + '.vcf'
        os.rename(f, newname)
```